# ¿Cómo leer un archivo almacenado en Assets en Android?

Tags: java, android

En el directorio `assets` de una aplicación en `Android`

Después de entender la diferencia de `res` vs `assets` de Android, he movido los documentos de ruta 'KML' al directorio `assets` de mi aplicación.

Deseo adaptar la siguiente función pero que lee el archivo directamente de la carpeta `assets`

ejemplo:
`assets/documento_track.kml`

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream readFileResource(int fileName) {

    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(fileName);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int ctr;
    try {
        ctr = inputStream.read();
        while (ctr != -1) {
            outputStream.write(ctr);
            ctr = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Log.v("Text Data", String.valueOf(outputStream.size()));
    return outputStream;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solventado:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream readFileFromAssets(Context context, String fileName) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int ctr;

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = context.getAssets().open(fileName);

        try {
            ctr = inputStream.read();
            while (ctr != -1) {
                outputStream.write(ctr);
                ctr = inputStream.read();
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Log.v("Text Data", String.valueOf(outputStream.size()));
    return outputStream;
}
```

Para usarla, si tenemos un archivo en `assets/miruta.kml`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = readFileFromAssets(this,"track-ruta.kml")

//Para obtener en formato String

byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ademas de leer un archivo como arreglo de bytes (byte array), también podemos requerir leer el contenido en forma de String de una archivo dentro de `/assets`, podemos leer archivos, `.txt`, `.html`, `.json`, `.xml` o `.kml` que en realidad es una extensión de `.xml`, etc. Este me parece el método mas sencillo:

```
public String readData(String inFile) {
    String sContent = "";
    try {
        InputStream stream = getAssets().open(inFile);
        int size = stream.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        stream.read(buffer);
        stream.close();
        sContent = new String(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error al leer el archivo!, " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return sContent;
}
```

Usando el método anterior, se realizaría de esta forma de esta forma:

```
String contenidoKML = readData("archivo.kml");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]