# Como exportar a formato multilinestring con mapinfo o qgis

Tags: android, google-maps, map, geolocalización

Tengo instalado el editor geográfico `mapinfo` y `qgis`.

Después de crear las rutas en `mapinfo` y guardarlas con extension `shp` y cargarla en `qgis` no sé cómo convertir esas rutas a`multilinestring`.

¿Con el `mapinfo` ya se puede convertir a `multilinestring`?

Comment: Porque no conviertes las rutas .shp a .kml para así cargarlas en googlemaps

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes la rutas guardadas en el directorio `assets` en tu aplicación, puedes usar la siguiente función [readFileFromAssets](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8407/c%C3%B3mo-leer-un-archivo-almacenado-en-assets-en-android)

Después con `.toString()` puedes obtener en formato `String` su contenido, pero si quieres mostrar rutas en el objeto googlemaps te recomiendo que las conviertes a `kml`, porque no se si soporta formato `.shp`

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar la Extensión de **Mapinfo (Tab)** a formato **Arcgis (Shape)** puedes hacerlo mediante el modulo **"Universal Converter"**, esta ubicado en el modulo **"tool"**, solo debes indicar la ubicación del archivo de entrada y asignarle la ubicación al archivo de salida...