# Leer un recurso XML en Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando mi primera app en Android en la que me gustaría leer un XML que he creado como un recurso. He leído algunos posts sobre la posibilidad que sea el encoding, pero lo he chequeado que es correcto. El código para leer el XML que he creado es el siguiente:

`Document doc = builder.parse(ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.xmlud1));`

El fichero XML es como el que se muestra a continuación, que está creado para testeo. Su codificación está probada en Notepad++, donde he podido confirmar que es UTF-8.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UD1>
    <Game1>
        <Q1>aaaa</Q1>
        <A1>ssa</A1>
    </Game1>
</UD1>
```

La excepción que me da es:

```
W/System.err: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT ������������0����...@4:420 in java.io.InputStreamReader@cc37506) 
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:147)
```

¿Alguien que me pueda echar una mano?

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Puedes revisar también : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8407/c%c3%b3mo-leer-un-archivo-almacenado-en-assets-en-android/8416#8416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los archivos en `res/xml` se leen usando `Resources.getXML()`.
Los archivos en `res/raw` se leen usando `Resources.openRawResource()`.

Según tu código, estás poniendo el archivo en `res/xml` pero lo estás leyendo como si estuviera en `res/raw`.

Si lo querés dejar en `res/xml`, leelos con `Resources.getXML()`.

[Documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Funcionando!! Error de novato!! :)

Answer (score 0):

En este caso lo correcto es usar la clase **[XmlResourceParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser)** , el archivo debes colocarlo dentro de res/xml

```
 XmlResourceParser xrp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.my_xml);
```

Este es un ejemplo completo:

```
 XmlResourceParser xrp = getResources().getXml(R.xml. xmlud1);

    try {

        int eventType = xrp.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                //System.out.println("Start document");
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                System.out.println("Start tag " + xrp.getName());
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                //System.out.println("End tag " + xrp.getName());
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                System.out.println("Text " + xrp.getText());
            }
            eventType = xrp.next();
        }



    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

De acuerdo a tu xml obtendrías los valores:

```
System.out: Start tag Q1
System.out: Text aaaa
System.out: End tag Q1
System.out: Start tag A1
```

---

Otra forma de realizarlo es almacenar tu xml en `/assets`, revisa:

[¿Cómo leer un archivo almacenado en Assets en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8407/c%c3%b3mo-leer-un-archivo-almacenado-en-assets-en-android/8416#8416)

dentro de `/assets`, podemos leer archivos, .txt, .html, .json, .xml o .kml

Comment: Muchas gracias! Al final lo resolví con la respuesta anterior, pero me lo anoto para futuros desarrollos!! Gracias!!